# Customizing nls_sort and nls_comp in Oracle

Tags: oracle, internationalization, nls

There is different letters for 'KAF' (ک , ك) and 'YA' (ی , ي) in Persian with different unicode codes and same spell.

I am using these commands to set Persian sort and comparing in my project

```
ALTER SESSION SET nls_sort=persian;

ALTER SESSION SET nls_comp =linguistic;
```

With setting `nls_comp` and `nls_sort` parameter I receieve these output

```
select first_name from customer 
where first_name like '%ك'; -- with result

select first_name from customer 
where first_name like '%ک';--with no result
```

How can receive same output for these queries?
Can I customize `nls_comp` ?

Comment: Have you investigated using regexp instead of like? Just reading around the topic it looks like there are character equivalences in Posix that might not be available in LIKE. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28298/ch5lingsort.htm#i1008619

Comment: I need a systemic solution. There is more than 200 tables and hundreds of queries in our project!